# iPhone - How to play video from memory data?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, rtsp

I am going to stream/play video on iPhone.

I received data from server with RTSP protocol. But I have to play it on iPhone.

The data of memory is not completed file that has buffer, it's length and presentation time and duration.

What's the best way to play this buffer?

Regard!